# web scraping with beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code to extract the latest MS office version for mac:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

quote_page = 'https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Update-history-
for-Office-2016-for-Mac-700cab62-0d67-4f23-947b-3686cb1a8eb7#bkmk_current'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
name_box = soup.find('p', attrs={'class': 'x-hidden-focus'})
print name_box
```

I'm trying to scrape Office 2016 for Mac (all applications)

15.39.0

I'm getting None as the output.

any help is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: There is no `x-hidden-focus` in the source code.

Comment: Interestingly it looks like elements only get the `x-hidden-focus` class when you right click on them (which I guess you were doing to inspect element). If you navigate to another `p` without right clicking on it and then right click on it, you can see this in action.

Comment: @dang, Your requirement is completely vague. Could you specify which line or table or a string or anything you wanna scrape?

Answer (score 0):

This works, explanation is given in comments.

```
import requests
import bs4

url = 'https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Update-history-for-Office-2016-for-Mac-700cab62-0d67-4f23-947b-3686cb1a8eb7#bkmk_current'

table_id = 'tblID0EAGAAA'
resp= requests.get(url)

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

# find table that contains data of interest
table = soup.find('table', {'id' : table_id})

# get the second row in that table
second_row = table.findAll('tr')[1]

# get the second column in that row
second_column = second_row.findAll('td')[1]

# get the content in this cell
version = second_column.find('p').text

print(version)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that doesn't depend on the `table id` (which very well could change after every release) or the ordering of the rows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

page = requests.get('https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Update-history-or-Office-2016-for-Mac-700cab62-0d67-4f23-947b-3686cb1a8eb7#bkmk_current')
pattern = re.compile(r'^Office.+Mac.*')

version = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser') \
            .select_one('section.ocpSection table tbody') \
            .find('p', text=pattern) \
            .parent \
            .find_next_sibling('td') \
            .select_one('p') \
            .text
print(version)
```