# Web Scrapping with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

To start, this is my first time using stack overflow!
I started my journey yesterday on python and I'm trying to extract the value of some pages automatically.

This is my code

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    url = 'https://www.jpg.store/collection/chilledkongs'
    r = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find('div', class_ = 'stat-title')
    print(div)
```

I'm getting nothing and my objective is to get the floor price. Atm is 888

Comment: It seems that the content on the website is being dynamically generated/rendered using JavaScript. BeautifulSoup only works on static site; to scrape more dynamic site you may need to use Selenium

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744992/web-scraping-with-beautiful-soup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The floor price is loaded via JavaScript from external source. To get it via `requests` use next example:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.jpg.store/collection/chilledkongs"
api_url = "https://server.jpgstoreapis.com/collection/{}/floor"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").contents[0]
data = json.loads(data)
policy_id = data["props"]["pageProps"]["collection"]["policy_id"]
data = requests.get(api_url.format(policy_id)).json()

print(data["floor"] / 1_000_000)
```

Prints:

```
888.0
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Bao Huynh Lamn stated, the website is being dynamically generated/rendered using JavaScript.So you can use  an automation tool like selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = 'https://www.jpg.store/collection/chilledkongs'
driver.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.close()
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'stat-title')[-2]:
    print(div.text)
```

Output:

```
888
```